# Transfer file.txt from Document to Python

Tags: terminal

From the terminal on mac OS X, I would like to transfer a `file.txt` from `Documents` to `Python`. Could anyone be able to tell me which command do I have to use for that?

[Image of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ6Gh.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you want is `mv Documents/file.txt Python/`. What this does is invoke the `mv` command (universal in *nix), with `Documents/file.txt` as the source file and `Python/` as the destination directory.